# How to use a particular select option to clear the filter in angularJS expression when the filter is applied to a particular JSON field?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to clear the filter for a particular option in select.

I am able to retrieve the values using other options from the desired field `name` in the JSON. But when I select`No Filter`, I want it to clear all the filters and display the entire JSON values.

Following is my code :

filter by anything:

```
          <select ng-model="select2.name" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in items">
               <option value="">No filter</option>
          </select>
       </div>

        <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: select2 ">
            {{ item.name }}: {{ item.fruit }}
        </div>
    </section>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom filter for that logic,

if you received selected value from dropdown as null you can return array as it is.

```
myApp.filter('filterServer', function () {
  return function (servers,initialState) {
  var filteredArray=[];
  if(!initialState)
    return servers;
  for (var k = 0; k < servers.length; ++k) {
    var server = servers[k];
    if (server.state == initialState) filteredArray.push(server);
    }
    return filteredArray;
  };
});
```

Here is demo sample http://fiddle.jshell.net/znhhw37v/1/

Note: I dont have your JSON so i created sample to simulate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If the filter expression returned undefined, then the filter would not apply. So, you could do something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listings | filter:(!!locationFilter || undefined) && {location: locationFilter}">
       {{item}}
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('YourModule', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listings = [{location: "foo"}, {location: "bar"}];
  
  $scope.locations = ["foo", "bar", "xyz"];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="YourModule">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="locationFilter" ng-options="l as l for l in locations">
      <option value="">all</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="item in listings | filter: (!!locationFilter || undefined) && {location: locationFilter}">{{item.location}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to update the filter with select2.name as its the model on which you are filtering. When you select No filter, model becomes "" and it automatically triggers the filter removal.

```html
<div>
  <select ng-model="select2.name" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in items">
    <option value="">No filter</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: select2.name ">
  {{ item.name }}: {{ item.fruit }}
</div>
```